# How to include 2 navigational properties in EF?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

An object in my database has 2 navigational properties (B and C):

```
Object A
{
  B bProperty

  C cProperty
}
```

I wish to include them both when querying object A.
I tried doing the following:

```
dbcontext.A.Include(x => x.B).ToList();
```

But how do I include C too?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

dbcontext.A.Include(x => x.B).Include(x => x.C).ToList();

I do it all in one go, so in my EF repository class, I have a method called GetAllIncluding which equals do it in a generic way for each entity,

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    var query = DbSet.AsNoTracking();

    query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));

    return query;
}
```

where DbSet is a private member of type IDbSet and T is a of type BaseEntity.

and the way I use it is like this

```
   MyGenericRepository<A>().GetAllIncluding(x=> x.B, x=> x.C).FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope that helps.