# How do I construct a function that allows me to pass in several includes for EF via params?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm writing an EF-backed repository that has a concept of packages associated to each entity type that does .Include for its commonly used children. For example, I have a function that looks like this

```
private static IQueryable<Foo> GetFooPackage(Entities context)
{
    return context.Foo
        .Include(target => target.Bar)
        .Include(target => target.FooBar)
}
```

This is so when I run my "get" methods, there's a consistent grouping of returned data. However, I want to be able to expand on that on a case by case basis. I want to be able to do something like

```
public static Foo GetFoo(int fooId, params Expression<Func<Foo, T>>[] extraIncludes)
{
    using (Entities context = GetContext(null))
    {
        IQueryable<Foo> package = GetFooPackage(context);

        extraIncludes.ToList().ForEach(expression => package.Include(expression));

        return package.FirstOrDefault(target => target.FooId == fooId);
    }
}
```

What's hanging me up is the T portion. I know the example doesn't properly reference the T generic. It's just a placeholder for the example. I'm unsure how to shape that so that I can do what I want. Ultimately, it's an effort to keep the SQL generated by EF as small and neat as possible. What would you suggest? It's being used in a disconnected service so I can't rely on lazy loading to simply fetch more data if it's missing. Once I grab the data, I need to get it in one go, and doing a second fetch really wouldn't be practical.

Thanks!

Comment: It seem you are overly complicating the code in order to make it dynamic.  Why don't you you just create a separate method for each unique data set returned?  Then call those methods when needed?

Comment: The answer was kind of obvious, and I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619532/how-to-include-2-navigational-properties-in-ef?rq=1

Comment: @CarlProthman I don't want to make a new method each time a different need arises. I like using the framework features when possible. The intent is clear and the goal is concise so I don't see it as an issue as I'm not trying to make a god method. I'm more amused and a bit embarrassed I didn't think of "object" as being the answer. Oi...

Comment: Just curious.  You must have dynamic UI then.  Because if you bring in an extra child data, you got to show that data in the UI.  Right? Or are you doing something different which requires dynamic child rows?

Comment: @CarlProthman It's more for dynamic processing. Most data scenarios can be satisfied by a core set of tables being brought along for each get. Sometimes, though, I need to really work those navigation properties to get to something in distant tables. Those associations are generally nonstandard in terms of how the repo is interacted with. If those scenarios change and become common, I realize it'd be better to denormalize the data a bit and simply get that in the package of includes.

Comment: Okay very good. You might want to put the solution you found as the answer to the question, then marked it solved. Have a great day!

Comment: @CarlProthman I tried. :) Stackoverflow turned it into a comment instead.

Comment: Scroll down to "Your Answer" then enter the solution (sometimes the Add comment looks like "Your Answer" textbox), then click "Post Your Answer" button.

Comment: @CarlProthman Yup, that's what I did before. I see a pretty blatant, blue "Answer Your Question" button. It's fairly distinct.

Comment: It may be due to not having enough Rep. Let me answer suggest an answer.  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    var query = DbSet.AsNoTracking();

    query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));

    return query;
}

MyGenericRepository<A>().GetAllIncluding(x=> x.B, x=> x.C).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer found here:  [How to include 2 navigational properties in EF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619532/how-to-include-2-navigational-properties-in-ef)

Comment: But when you see transformed SQL for this LINQ, the above includes always shows inner joins. Is there a way you could achive left or right joins using the same method of includes. For reference I'm including my post link stackoverflow.com/questions/55129505/… Thanks.

Comment: At first this seemed like the solution for my situation, but I hit a brick wall when I needed entity tracking in the context. `DbSet.AsNoTracking` rules out this approach for those who need tracking.

Answer (score 3):

For those unable to use the accepted answer due to `DbSet.AsNoTracking`, here's an alternative:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Retrieve(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] relations)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.Entities;

    foreach (var relation in relations)
        query = query.Include(relation);

    return query;
}
```

This version loops through the array of relations and expands the query with each iteration.